# Objective-C Challenges/Examples

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm currently learning objective-c. I have heard (and experienced) that the best way to learn is doing it yourself, trying to reach a goal. For example, trying to code a simple app and having trouble completing it, then persevering and accomplishing your goal, meanwhile learning a lot. Hopefully you know what I mean. Well it's hard for me to come up with challenging programs/applications to code. I'm wondering if there is somewhere that someone has listed a few challenges (i.e. "try and make the program do this")  or examples like at the end of each chapter of the book, "Programming in Objective-C, 4th edition" or the book "Objective-C for Absolute Beginners". Does anybody know of a website that has a few of these or does anybody want to help me by challenging me? (I'm a super beginner so not to challenging.) Thanks for your time and answers. :D

Comment: StackOverflow is not really where you would ask these types of questions (here is where you'd ask a question once you get stuck in one of your challenges and you need some help regarding a specific issue you're having).

Comment: I would suggest working your way through some of Apple's tutorials to get a feel of Objective-C and how things are done, and then start trying to find challenges. It's important to get the fundamentals ingrained first, because without that you'll only end up wasting time and effort.

Comment: Rather than looking for pre-made problems to challenge yourself, find a problem that you would like to solve. Break it down into the simplest steps required to make an application that addresses this problem. Attack each of these steps in turn as self-contained challenges, and you'll quickly find yourself learning the language and frameworks. This is how I got started on Cocoa, and at the end I had a working product I could distribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some excellent non-language-specific coding challenges at [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/problems). They are mathematically focussed, so the more advanced ones may not help you learn Objective-C so much as mathematics.

The way I learned Objective-C was by porting an open-source python program (i.e. rewriting the program in Objective-C). I thought it was a particularly good way to learn because I had to constantly learn about Obj-C conventions, and many python features are not available in Obj-C, so I had to write them.